# How do I upload a document to SharePoint with android?

Tags: java, android, sharepoint

I dev a android app , how can I upload a file to sharepoint with android?
file is large.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via web services. If you on SharePoint 2013 - it's have REST services for this. Just make PUT request and you done. If it SharePoint 2010 - you need requests to SOAP services.
There is article about uploading in SharePoint 2013: [Uploading Files Using the REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques.aspx) 
There is about 2010 version: [Upload documents to SharePoint 2010](http://cecildt.blogspot.ru/2010/10/upload-documents-to-sharepoint-2010.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but "Upload documents to SharePoint 2010" is not java.server is SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @love_mark, can you consume soap service in java? Google says than it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int uploadFile(String directoryPath, String file_path){
        if (siteHost.isEmpty() || !isLogin) return ERROR_LOGIN;

        String webserviceUrl = "http://site:port/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/SharedDocuments";
        String slug = "http://site:port/Shared%20Documents/filename";

        File file = new File(file_path);
        if (file == null) return ERROR_FILE;
        String file_name = file.getName();
        ContentBody filebody = new FileBody(file);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(webserviceUrl);

        post.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
        post.setHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
        post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:28.0) Gecko/28.0 Firefox/28.0");
        post.addHeader("Slug",slug);

        MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartContent.addPart(file_name, filebody);
        post.setEntity(multipartContent);        ;

        try {
            HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(post);
            int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (resCode != 201) return ERROR_UPLOAD;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            return ERROR_UPLOAD;
        }

        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }
```